# How to subdivide keeping the form of the curve_

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, subdivision-surface, smooth

I've made the modeling of an object, and now I would like so subdivide it. When I go to edit mode, Edge, subdivide. It creates the line between the two nearest vertex but all in the same surface; I would like it to keep the form, to add resolution.

Before subdivide:

[image: Surface before]

After subdivide:

[image: Surface after subdivide]

Desired result:

[image: Desired result]

I would like to make the curve smoother. In this case this "curve" is paralell to the grid, but If I want to make the same with a "curve" that varies in a 3D way, I understand that the new vertices should be along some normals?

PD: I want to increase the poligons because I would like to 3D print the object so I need a "smooth" surface.

Thanks in advance

Edit 1:
This is the model I'm trying to model. I know that the topology specially on the little door is very bad.

[image: Object]

If I add the subdivison surface modifier this happens:

Modifier:

[image: Modifier]

Result:

[image: Modifier result]

The lower edge gets cramped end veri far from wireframe and the cannon...

Comment: This is how the Subdivide operation works, use the Subdivision Surface modifier instead and apply it.

Comment: @moonboots if I use that modifier, the mesh becomes weird and gets deformed

Comment: Yes because this may not be what you want fir the whole mesh, so you need to find another solution please share your object

Comment: @moonboots now you can see the object and the modifier applied (under edit 1)

Comment: It's not clear what part you are trying to smooth, also maybe you should show a reference image of your object, and redo it from scratch?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the *Relax* operation. Activate the *LoopTools* addon, select the edges (in *Edge Select* mode) and RMB > *LoopTools > Relax*:

[image]

Comment: @Javepan And make sure you use the _Relax_ option from the _Loop Tools_ - because there is also a _Relax_ function at the bottom of the context menu, which works a bit different and might change the overall shape too much.

Answer (score 3):

*Subdivide* comes with a 'Smoothness' setting, which appears to need some definition of a vertex-normal to work with:

[image]

In the absence of faces, normals appear to be derived from vector-to-object-origin. The 'Factor' limit is soft, it can be set to more than 1.

If the geometry of interest comprises well-formed quad loops, the shipped add-on *Loop Tools > Curve* is applicable:

[image]

Selected vertices in a loop are pinned, the remainder are interpolated between them according to the operator's settings. (Here, vertices to be pinned are selected with 'Select Next Active' <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad+</kbd>)

Comment: If you want a good description of how Loop Tools > Curve works, I think Ian McGlasham's 'Panel Beating'  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=goJ4LVHXkC4) is a good start. That may be helpful reshaping your model in general